# Print the count of numbers that are divisible either by 3 or 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list of n integers, count the number of integers in the list that are either a multiple of 3 or a multiple of 5. (All the numbers are guaranteed to be distinct).

Input Format:

Single line of input contains a list of space separated integers

Output Format:

Print the count of numbers that are divisible either by 3 or 5

Example:

Input:

1 3 5 6 7 9 11 13 15 18 20 21

Output:

8

My Code:

```
x=input()
a=list(map(float, input().strip().split()))[:x]
c=0
for i in range(1,x+1):
  if ((i%3==0) & (i%5==0)):
    c=c+1
    print(c, end="")
```

output after running my code:

[image: output after running my code]

Comment: Please note: You are testing for numbers divisible 3 **and** 5 not 3 **or** 5. You also probably don't want to use the bitwise operators if you don't need.

Comment: `sum(not(n % 3 and n % 5) for n in map(int, input().split()))`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, you don't have to use 2x `input()` (one time is sufficient). Also, don't convert the numbers to `float`, the `int` is sufficient:

```py
# your input, you can substitute for `s = input()` later:
s = "1 3 5 6 7 9 11 13 15 18 20 21"

# convert numbers to integer:
numbers = [int(n) for n in s.split()]

print(sum(n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0 for n in numbers))
```

Prints:

```
8
```

---

NOTE:

`n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0` will give us `True` or `False`. We can use `sum()` here to sum `True` values together (`True` is equal to `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
a=list(map(float, input().split()))
c=0
for i in a:
  if (i%3==0) or (i%5==0):
    c=c+1
print(c, end="")
```